# Entity Framework Include - Only Load One Side of Relationship

Tags: entity-framework

How do I tell Entity Framework to load only one-side of a relationship? E.g.

```
ctx.Customers.Include("Orders")
```

will load the Orders property for each Customer, but for each Order, its Customer property will also be filled in. How do I prevent the latter?

Comment: Why would anyone need that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The circular reference issue. I don't want to add $id and $ref to the payload if I can avoid it.

Comment: Removing the Customer property from the Order class is not an option because for some other scenarios, I have an Order entity and I have to .Load() its Customer property